# mount a subdirectory without intermediate mount

Tags: mount

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
# mount /dev/node /mnt/intermediate
# mount --bind /mnt/intermediate/sub/dir /final/mountpoint
```

I'd like to do it in a single command, though, without use of the intermediate mount point, `/mnt/intermediate`. Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps a symlink could work? `ln -s /mnt/intermediate/sub/dir /final/mountpoint` (do this while the node is mounted at `/mnt/intermediate`). then you only need to mount the intermediate.

Comment: @Mioriin no, the idea is not to have /mnt/intermediate at all.

Comment: Note that it is possible to 1) create a temporary directory with `mktemp`, 2) *unmount the temporary after binding the sub-directory*.  Otherwise, you need the shiny new mount API which hasn't been merged so far. https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/CAHk-=whysoVxJU8+TBw=D3xN00HOOqg-9Chc=i0Pt+Ozm3Z0Tg@mail.gmail.com/ / https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/153754740781.17872.7869536526927736855.stgit@warthog.procyon.org.uk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in general you can't mount a sub directory of a file system, unless that file system specifically supports it.

Support for sub directory mounting is sometimes found in network file systems, like NFS or SMB, where you can mount a sub directory of an exported file system.

BTRFS has the option `subvol`, but that is file system specific.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [experimental option for `mount`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/mount.8#:%7E:text=X%2Dmount.subdir%3Ddirectory) that can be accessed through `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
UUID=<some_uuid>     <dir>     <type>     <other options>,X-mount.subdir=<subdirectory>    <dump>    <fsck>
```

Comment: (1) The `mount(8)` man page you linked to says “this feature is implemented by temporary filesystem root directory mount in unshared namespace and then bind the sub-directory to the final mount point and umount the root of the filesystem.” And the OP says “the idea is not to have /mnt/intermediate at all.” So it’s debatable how well this answers the question. (2) Since the question asks for a command, it would be better if your answer showed how to do this as a command.

Comment: Yeah, @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' is right on both counts. But if I could do it using a single command instead of two, I'd consider that an improvement. Is X-mount.subdir accessible from the -o argument of a mount command?

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist: [The man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/mount.8) that Nick Anthony Miras linked to lists `X-mount` as a “filesystem-independent mount option”, along with ``[rel]atime``, `ro`, ``[no]suid``, `sync` and other familiar ones.  The lead-in paragraph says “Some of these options are only useful when they appear in the `/etc/fstab` file.” but it doesn’t state any such restriction on `X-mount`.